# Property only accessible via message passing (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

For some reason I cannot access the view as a property

```
MyAppDelegate *APPDELEGATE=((MexicanWaveAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]);
[APPDELEGATE.viewController view];
APPDELEGATE.viewController.view; //Accessing unknown 'view' component of a property
```

I have been able to access view as a property for other view controllers and it is a property in the doc. Can you explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually caused because my app delegate .h file (`MexicanWaveAppDelegate.h`) didn't contain information about what type the view controller (`MexicanWaveViewController`) was. This means that any class importing `MexicanWaveAppDelegate.h` would have its `MexicanWaveViewController` property as an 'opaque type' (a type about which no information is known).

This problem can be solved by changing `MexicanWaveAppDelegate.h` in either of the following ways:

- Importing the "MexicanWaveViewController.h"
- Providing a forward declaration for MexicanWaveViewController

Answer (score 1):

Either **APPDELEGATE.viewController** is not of type **UIViewController** (or a derived class), or you didn't include the header for **MexicanWaveAppDelegate** (MexicanWaveAppDelegate.h)

Comment: It actually wasn't either of these, but your answer was very helpful