# Breaking circular references while maintaining access to attributes (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c

I have two classes (`Test1` and `Test2`) that each have a property (`test2` and `test1` respectively) pointing to an instance of the other class. This means that `Test1.m` must import `Test2.h` and `Test2.m` must import `Test1.h`. The .h files must also have a forward declaration. Unfortunately, this means that I cannot access the attributes of `test2` and `test1` with dot notation. I can access them with message passing, but I should be able to use either notation. How can I resolve this problem?

**Related**

- [Strange behavior for view property of view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175168/strange-behaviour-for-view-property-of-view-controller)

**Test1**

```
//Test1.h

@class Test2;

@interface Test1 : NSObject {
 Test2* test2;
 int a1;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Test2* test2;

-  (void)meth1;

@end

//Test1.m
#import "Test1.h"
#import "Test2.h"

@implementation Test1

@synthesize test2;

-  (void)meth1{
 test2.a2;//Request for member 'a2' in something not a structure or union
}

@end
```

**Test2**

```
//Test2.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Test1;

@interface Test2 : NSObject {
 Test1 *test1;
 int a2;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) Test1* test1;

-  (void)meth2;

@end

//Test2.m
#import "Test2.h"
#import "Test1.h"

@implementation Test2

@synthesize test1;

-  (void)meth2{
 test1.a1;//Request for member 'a1' in something not a structure or union
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding properties for and synthesizing a1 & a2 seems to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access a1 and a2 outside of the class they belong to, I'd **strongly** recommend defining them as properties.

However, if you *really* want to avoid message passing, you can define them as public in the header:

```
@interface Test2 : NSObject {
 Test1 *test1;
 @public 
   int a2;
}
```

and access them like this:

```
-  (void)meth1{
    test2->a2;
}
```

Comment: Ooph... I don't think public ivars are the right way to do this.  They're generally discouraged unless you have a *very* good reason for exposing them (ie, your accessors are performance bottlenecks).

Comment: Thanks, I should have been clearer that I don't have anything against message passing, just that I should be able to use either dot notation or message passing notation

Comment: @Dave Delong: I agree, which is why I prefaced by recommending to use properties.